# How much money does one need to deposit in order to move to Germany for education?

Tags: education

I want to move to Germany for a masters in Computer Science. I am looking for the amount of money needed to deposit in order to move to Germany. Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about academia. You can probably receive this type of information from the German embassy in your country.

Comment: Student in Germany here. Germany is divided into "federal lands". You'll need  certain amount of €€€ on the account for the student visa and then a certain amount of €€€ for residence permit later on. Exact amount for the residence permit depends on the land. In Schleswig Holstein, it's 670€/month, but again, it will depend on what local government decides, because federal government gives visas and local government gives residence permits.

Comment: Hi @AndrejaKo: I am asking about the amount of money one needs to deposit for moving. Like below link mentions its 7,908 Euros.
https://www.study-in.de/en/plan-your-studies/requirements/8000-euros-for-one-year_27533.php

Comment: @Fahad Uddin And I'm giving comment exactly about that. As I mentioned, you'll need a certain amount of money, that seems to depend on your country (so you need to ask local embassy about that) for the visa that's usually issued for 3 months. Later on, you'll need a certain amount of money that depends on the land where you are to get the residence permit. You'll need to ask the local "Ausländerbehörde" for the place where you'll be staying.

Comment: Here's a link supporting what @AndrejaKo wrote: http://www.internationale-studierende.de/fragen_zur_vorbereitung/einreise/finanzierungsnachweis/ "Die deutschen Behörden gehen dabei von einem bestimmten Mindestbetrag aus, den Sie im Monat zur Verfügung haben müssen. Dieser liegt zurzeit bei 670 Euro pro Monat, das sind insgesamt 8040 Euro für das erste Studienjahr. Allerdings können eventuell auch höhere Nachweise verlangt werden. [...] **Erkundigen Sie sich unbedingt bei der deutschen Botschaft in Ihrem Land, in welcher Form Sie den Nachweis erbringen müssen!**"

Comment: @bers You could post that as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Your own link to [Deutscher Akademischer Austauschdienst](https://www.study-in.de/en/plan-your-studies/requirements/8000-euros-for-one-year_27533.php), the German Academic Exchange Service, is under the auspices of the Federal Ministry of Education and Research.  The 8700 Euro is an estimate, based on the average amounts students need to cover food, accommodation, transportation, books, and the like.

[Deutsches Studentenwerk](http://www.internationale-studierende.de/fragen_zur_vorbereitung/einreise/finanzierungsnachweis/) confirms:

> In order to obtain a visa, you must prove that you can finance your studies. At least the first year of your studies must be fully funded. The German authorities assume a certain minimum amount that must be available in the month. At the moment this is 720 Euro per month, which is a total of 8640 Euro for the first year of study. However, higher proofs may also be required.

However, there may be additional fees/tuition associated with Masters and PhD degrees and [Masters Portal](http://www.mastersportal.eu/articles/358/university-tuition-fees-and-living-costs-in-germany-low-cost-german-degrees.html) has resources to help you estimate what those might be.